# Angular2 error on local WAMP server

Tags: html, angular, routes

I'm trying to run a Angular2 app from WAMP on my local pc.
I develop the app from the wamp/www folder and test it at different stages both from `localhost:3000` and `localhost/myapp` (liteserver and wamp)

All works fine until i try to add `<base href="/">` to Index.html right below the `<head>`.
At that point, only in Wamp i get the error: `ReferenceError: System is not defined`

**Is there any workaround or fix to get past this error? (and move to the next one :) )**

This is my Index.html.

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<title>Firebase</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
   <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Update:**
  LiteServer working, Folder Structure, and main.ts:

[image: lite server]

WAMP, Index.html
    [image: wamp]

Comment: Try this: document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');

Comment: could you post your directory structure?

Comment: Can you check your browser console if System.js is loaded and included?

Comment: Updated the post. Looks like most files are giving 404 after i add `<base href="/">` to `Index.html` , but can't tell why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just reading about the new [angular2 router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) and i thought to try this:

> `<base href=".">`

and it just works with no further errors!!

I can't tell why, but both wamp and liteserver work fine now, even though in all tutorials about router they all show this method: `<base href="/">`. I hope this will help someone else to waste less time on this silly thing then i did.